# memory double allocation with shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I have a memory allocation problem where `std::shared_ptr` is being allocated twice:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> list;

std::shared_ptr<int> test (int i) {
    list.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(i));
    return list.back();
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> a  = test(5);
}
```

Valgrind output:

`==28524== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28524==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28524==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 48 bytes allocated
==28524==`

This happens with pretty much all `std` containers. I only call `std::make_shared` once.

Why do I get 2 allocs when I only run `std::make_shared` once? How do I only have 1 alloc, if possible? Is this proper coding or can I make this more efficient?

Comment: Do you have any questions?

Comment: 1 allocation for the shared_ptr + 1 allocation in the vector

Comment: There no memory leak, so I don't understand what problem you might have?

Comment: @Dieter, shouldn't it just make a copy of the pointer instead of reallocating it?

Comment: @user263688 No, you have two objects maintaining allocated memory.

Comment: At the very least, you would have one `int` allocated on the heap with `make_shared`, and one list node allocated with `list::push_back`.

Comment: @user263688 Copy from stack to the another allocated place? std::list dynamically allocates memory for its internal structures.

Comment: By the way, why on Earth are you making a vector of `shared_ptr<int>`. This is a toy example, right?

Comment: Further to the comment about the allocation in the vector vs the shared_ptr: Change your code to push_back a null shared_ptr<int> to verify this for yourself.

Comment: Despite the comments here, I think this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @gd1, because I want to make sure I have no memory leaks. How would I do it otherwise? I'm using `<int>` as a simple example, I'm using more complex classes in my code.

Comment: @user263688 That's what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that valgrind tells you is that there were two allocations. It doesn't tell you what sort of objects were being allocated.

It's worth testing a base case:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> list;

int test (int i) {
    list.push_back(i);
    return list.back();
}

int main() {
    int a  = test(5);
}
```

Here we will see that one region is allocated: the contents of the `std::vector`:

```
==10570== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10570==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10570==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 4 bytes allocated
==10570== 
==10570== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Similarly, if you only use a shared_ptr, you also end up with one allocation:

```
#include <memory>

std::shared_ptr<int> test (int i) {
    return std::make_shared<int>(i);
}

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> a  = test(5);
}
```

```
==10601== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10601==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10601==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 32 bytes allocated
==10601== 
==10601== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

So naturally, when you have both a shared_ptr and a container, you end up with two allocations, as valgrind reports. (The container allocation is larger with a container of shared_ptrs than with a container of ints, because a shared_ptr is larger than an int.)